# How to summarise a table by 2 columns in R

Tags: r, aggregate, split-apply-combine

I would like to summarise this data set by grouping 1st by period, and 2nd by Payer id so that results are shown as subtotal for any given user by month as follows:

data.frame:

```
Payer   Period
1   10  1-1015
2   15  2-1015
3   14  3-1015
1   1   1-1015
3   5   1-1015
1   7   4-1015
3   8   4-1015
1   4   5-1015
```

And results should look like this:

```
Payer   Period
1   11  1-1015
3   5   1-1015
2   15  2-1015
3   14  3-1015
1   7   4-1015
3   8   4-1015
1   4   5-1015
```

Which is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to order first by period and then by payer?

Comment: Was the `$` the name of a column? (I removed it in my edit because I thought it was there by mistake)

Comment: You have one column name missing.  If there is an ID column, `aggregate(Payer~ID+Period, df1, FUN=sum)`

Comment: Let's call the missing middle column name `Amount`...

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst thanks, I meant summing the totals by payer for every month

Comment: @akrun exacty. the $ column is Amount

Comment: depends on what you mean by *best*, really. If you want a fast way to do this with a flexible syntax, check out the [data.table package tutorials](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) (@akrun's answer). See also [benchmarks on grouping](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping).

Answer (score 4):

You can just do `aggregate` assuming that there are three columns.

```
 aggregate(Amount~., df1, FUN=sum)
 #    Payer Period Amount
 #1     1 1-1015     11
 #2     3 1-1015      5
 #3     2 2-1015     15
 #4     3 3-1015     14
 #5     1 4-1015      7
 #6     3 4-1015      8
 #7     1 5-1015      4
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df1)[, list(Amount=sum(Amount)), .(Period, Payer)]
 #    Period Payer Amount
 #1: 1-1015     1     11
 #2: 2-1015     2     15
 #3: 3-1015     3     14
 #4: 1-1015     3      5
 #5: 4-1015     1      7
 #6: 4-1015     3      8
 #7: 5-1015     1      4
```

Using a different order

```
 aggregate(Amount~., df2, FUN=sum)
 #  Payer Period Amount
 #1     1 1-1015     11
 #2     3 1-1015      5
 #3     2 2-1015     15
 #4     3 3-1015     14
 #5     1 4-1015      7
 #6     3 4-1015      8
 #7     1 5-1015      4
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Payer = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), 
 Amount = c(10L, 
 15L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 4L), Period = c("1-1015", "2-1015", 
 "3-1015", "1-1015", "1-1015", "4-1015", "4-1015", "5-1015")),
 .Names = c("Payer", 
  "Amount", "Period"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

 set.seed(24)
 df2 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
```

Comment: This relies on the dataset having all entries in order of increasing Period, Payer. If any of the entries aren't, the result will be out of order.

Comment: @smci. I do not think that is true in either instance. Neither `aggregate` nor the "by" argument to `data.table.[`  require their arguments to be ordered by group.

Comment: I think @smci was thinking of sas :}

Comment: God no, I wouldn't touch SAS or SPSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Period,Payer) %>%
    summarize(Amount = sum(Amount)) %>%
    ungroup() # this should ungroup by the last grouped var, i.e. Payer

# if that doesn't work, then add an explicit %>% arrange(Period, Payer)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you choose to use this over `aggregate`?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst: I thought the aggregate did not give explicit ordering by Period, Payer (as the OP asked for). But it does. So this is just a dplyr equivalent to the aggregate. dplyr(/data.table) almost surely performs better for high cardinality grouping, i.e. large files.